# What "older versions of sh" that source in $ENV even for non-interactive shells are there?

Tags: shell, security, environment-variables

In FreeBSD 13.1's `man sh`, in the "Invocation" section, it mentions:

> Unlike older versions of sh the ENV script is only sourced on invocation of interactive shells.  This closes a well-known, and sometimes easily exploitable security hole related to poorly thought out ENV scripts.

I am in the process of trying to unify my bazillion ad hoc shell startup files, on different computers with different operating systems and, presumably, with different flavors and versions of `sh`. To do so, I would like to try to figure out if it's at all likely that I will ever need to account for such older versions.

Are these "older versions" things like "If you're using `sh` on an unupgraded OS from 1972, you have to worry about this" (in which case I seriously doubt that I'd ever need to worry about it)?

Or are there vaguely modern things that still operate this way, in which case I might need to worry about it? For example, "If you're using Debian, you only have to worry about this if you're using a pre-10.0 release; if you're using Cygwin, you have to worry about this no matter what your release version is; if your `sh` is actually `pdksh`, then you have to worry about it in such-and-such situations".

Comment: FWIW, `bash`, when not invoked as `sh` does source `$BASH_ENV` even when non-interactive (it doesn't perform expansions in its value though like is done for `$ENV`.

Comment: What kind of thing are you worrying about? If you're talking about *shell startup files*, is that about interactive invocations of the shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. My question is based upon the fact that the man page explicitly says that (unspecified) "older versions" of sh would source in $ENV *regardless* of whether the shell is interactive or not.

Comment: And if they do how/why would it be a problem in your use case?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, oh, I don't know specifically, but in general they apparently can be ("a well-known, and sometimes easily exploitable security hole related to poorly thought out ENV scripts").
Anyway, the point of my question is that I would prefer to not spend time thinking about what these problematic situations may be, or how to avoid them, and if "old" means "1972", then I don't have to.